# C++ generate a summary of the strings from a text file

Tags: c++

i have a textfile which contains the following strings:

```
Employee:HoursWorked:PayPerHour:DateWorked
John:5:4:25Jan14
Amy:3:6:25Jan14
Will:4:7:27Jan14
Alan:7:3:25Jan14
```

What i'm trying to do is to generate a daily salary report which would look like this:

```
Date          Total Salary
25Jan14       59
27Jan14       28
```

As im still new to C++, so far what i could only do is generate this output:

```
Date: 25Jan14
Total Salary: 20
Date: 25Jan14
Total Salary: 18
Date: 27Jan14
Total Salary: 28
Date: 25Jan14
Total Salary: 21
```

Below is my code:

```
    string date, fname, fhour, fpay, fdate;
    int ihour, ipay, total, gtotal;
    ifstream file ("salary.txt");


            while (file) 
            {
                    getline(file, fname, ':'); 
                    getline(file, fhour, ':'); 
                    getline(file, fpay, ':');
                    getline(file, fdate);
                    ihour = atoi(fhour.c_str());
                    ipay = atoi(fpay.c_str());



                            cout << "Date: " << fdate << endl;
                            total = ihour * ipay;
                            gtotal += total; //Suppose to store the grand total of a single date
                            cout << "Total Salary: " << total << endl;
  }
```

How do i make the output such that it would only display a single 25Jan14 date with the salary added up? I have tried to google for solution but i had no idea what to search for at all.

Please advice, thanks.

Comment: It's a one-liner in `awk`: `awk -F: 'NR>1{a[$4]+=$2*$3} END{print "Date\tTotal Salary";for(i in a) print i,a[i]}' salary.txt` ;)

Comment: @PaulEvans Except it's not in `C++`. :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to store `salary` associated with their corresponding `date`, and then sum all salaries together for the same dates.

Comment: Should i use vector to do that?

Comment: i am a little confused on how to associate the salary with the date, could you elaborate on this?

Comment: @user3234825 You can use a `vector<pair<string, int>>`.

Comment: i have manage to store the values into a vector pair, but how do i do a comparison such that if the date are same, the salary will be added up? i tried using this if statement to check:     if (vdatetotal[i].first == vdate[i]) but then i realize that doesn't make sense cause the date will definitely be the same.

Comment: @user3234825 Then check their `string` is equal or not, add them if equal.

Comment: i tried using vector array to compare the string, however it only works if i manually set a index, is there a better way to do this?

Comment: @user3234825 You don't need to set a index, you just loop through the `vector`.